# When a creature comes back to the battlefield from the graveyard, does it trigger its abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm talking of course about abilities that trigger "when entering the battlefield". For instance the [Channeler Initiate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChanneler%20Initiate%5d) is returned from the graveyard, does it require to put 3 -1/-1 counters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, enters-the-battlefield abilities triggers regardless of a permanent's previous zone, unless explicitly stated.

[Channeler Initiate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChanneler%20Initiate%5d) will force you to put -1/-1 counters when coming into play, regardless of it being played from your hand, coming back from the graveyard, from exile, etc...

Here's the related bit of rules :

> 603.6a Enters-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent enters the battlefield. These are written, “When [this object] enters the battlefield, . . . “ or “Whenever a [type] enters the battlefield, . . .” Each time an event puts one or more permanents onto the battlefield, all permanents on the battlefield (including the newcomers) are checked for any enters-the-battlefield triggers that match the event.

Comment: For more fun with 'Enters the Battlefield' and what zone the card was in before: [Phage the Untouchable](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382324)

Answer (score 1):

When any creature is placed on the battlefield from any location (hand, deck, exile, graveyard) it has "entered the battlefield." Therefore, yes, "When ~ enters the battlefield" effects do apply.